# Open Chrome Web App using GCM

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, web-push, chrome-gcm, push-api

I am able to send a message to a Chrome Web App using GCM.  I am using a http post to:  https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send 
sending registrationid, applicationid, and senderid values.  The message shows as a Chrome Notification on my screen.  My question is - is there a command or a GCM event/function I can use to start the Chrome Web App?  Google Chrome is set to run in the background.

This is my GCM Listener for message event:

```
chrome.gcm.onMessage.addListener(messageReceived);
```

It calls the `messageReceived` function and in this function I get message, pop notification on the screen, and open/create the window:

```html
chrome.notifications.create(getNotificationId(), {
    title: 'GCM Message',
    iconUrl: 'gcm_128.png',
    type: 'basic',
    message: messageString
  }, function() {});
  
  // Center window on screen.
  var screenWidth = screen.availWidth;
  var screenHeight = screen.availHeight;
  var width = 500;
  var height = 300;
  chrome.app.window.create('register.html', {
    id: "helloWorldID",
    outerBounds: {
      width: width,
      height: height,
      left: Math.round((screenWidth-width)/2),
      top: Math.round((screenHeight-height)/2)
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot start chrome directly from the code that receives the push message. However once the notification is clicked you can use http://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#client-focus to see if there is already a window opened or http://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#client-navigate to open a new window.

https://tests.peter.sh/notification-generator/ is a good sample site where you can play with the different options.

Answer (score 0):

This is my GCM Listener for message event:
chrome.gcm.onMessage.addListener(messageReceived);

It calls messageReceived function and in this function I get message, pop notification on the screen, and open/create the window:

```html
chrome.notifications.create(getNotificationId(), {
    title: 'GCM Message',
    iconUrl: 'gcm_128.png',
    type: 'basic',
    message: messageString
  }, function() {});
  
  // Center window on screen.
  var screenWidth = screen.availWidth;
  var screenHeight = screen.availHeight;
  var width = 500;
  var height = 300;
  chrome.app.window.create('register.html', {
    id: "helloWorldID",
    outerBounds: {
      width: width,
      height: height,
      left: Math.round((screenWidth-width)/2),
      top: Math.round((screenHeight-height)/2)
    }
  });
}
```